# ZSH prompt substitution issues

Tags: zsh, prompt, ansi-escape

I've searched through several answers here and through Google, but I'm still not sure what's going wrong with my prompt.

According to the documentation I've read, this should work

```
setopt prompt_subst
autoload -U colors && colors
PROMPT="%{[00m[38;5;245m%}test %D%{[00m%}"
```

My prompt is the following, however:

```
[00m[38;5;245mtest 15-07-01[00m
```

Note that the date expansion actually worked, so prompt substitution is working.  The ZSH man pages for prompt expansion states that `%{...%}` should be treated as a raw escape code, but that doesn't seem to be happening.  Passing that string to `print -P` also results in the output above.  I've found example prompts on the Internet for ZSH that also seem to indicate that the above syntax should work. See [this](https://github.com/sykora/etc/blob/master/zsh/prompt.zsh) for one example - the $FG and $FX arrays are populated with escape codes and are defined [here](https://github.com/sykora/etc/blob/master/zsh/functions/spectrum).  I've tried this example directly by merging both the files above, adding `setopt prompt_subst` to the beginning just to make sure it's set, then sourcing it and the prompt is a mess of escape codes.

The following works

```
setopt prompt_subst
autoload -U colors && colors
PROMPT=$'%{\e[00m\e[38;5;245m%}test %D%{\e[00m%}'
```

I get the expected result of `test 15-07-01` in the proper color.

I've tested this on ZSH 5.0.5 in OSX Yosimite, 5.0.7 from MacPorts, and 4.3.17 on Debian, with the same results.  I know I have provided a valid solution to my own problem here with the working example, but I'm wondering why the first syntax isn't working as it seems it should.

Comment: There is no problem here; if the documentation you are reading omits the escape character, it's wrong. The ANSI codes that instruct the terminal to switch colors all begin with `ESC[`, not just `[`.

Comment: Note that it's easier to use the built-in escapes for changing the color than to deal with the raw control sequences. `prompt="%F{245}test %D%f"`

Comment: You might be assuming that `%{ ... %}` provides the escape character for the beginning of each sequence; what it actually does is just instructs the shell that the contents of the braces occupy zero space in the output, so that the correct on-screen length of the prompt can be computed.

Comment: The man page for zshmisc states that "%{...%} Include a string as a literal escape sequence.  The string within the braces should not change the cursor position.  Brace pairs can nest."  That seems to indicate that the contents SHOULDN'T change the cursor position, not that that's a function of the `%{...%}` itself.  It does state that the contents will be treated as a literal escape sequence.  I'm confused because I have seen allegedly working examples that do not include the escape character `ESC[` inside the `%{...%}` sequence.

Comment: The documentation is poorly worded. Escape sequences don't consist of printable characters; the entire thing is interpreted by the terminal rather than being displayed. If you *did* put printable characters inside the braces, then your prompt would actually be *longer* than `zsh` computed, compared to the prompt being shorter than `zsh` computed if you didn't use `%{...%}` at all.

Comment: I do understand that the braces tell zsh that the content between should be treated as zero length. I know ANSI escape codes pretty well, too. I'm just new to ZSH. I find it difficult to see how the config files I linked to are supposed to work. The spectrum file is even used in oh-my-zsh (which I am purposefully not using as anything other than an example - I like to know how my config files are written and what they do).

Comment: You might want to ask the author of those files directly; I see no reason why they should work, and you've confirmed for yourself that they don't.

Answer (score 0):

I think this all has to do with the timeless and perennial problem of escaping. It's worth reminding ourselves what escaping means, briefly: an escape character is an indicator to the computer that what follows should not be output literally.

So there are 2 escaping issues with:
`PROMPT="%{[00m[38;5;245m%}test %D%{[00m%}"`

1. Firstly, the colour escape sequences (eg; `[00m`) should all start with the control character like so `\e[00m`. You may have also seen it written as `^[00m` and `\003[00m`. What I suspect has happened is one of the variations has suffered the common fate of being inadvertently escaped by either the copy/paste of the author or the website's framework stack, whether that be somewhere in a database, HTTP rendering or JS parsing. The control character (ie, `^`, `\e` or `\003`), as you probably know, does not have a literal representation, say if you press it on the keyboard. That's why a web stack might decide to not display anything if it sees it in a string. So let's correct that now:

   > `PROMPT="%{\e[00m\e[38;5;245m%}test %D%{\e[00m%}"`
2. This actually nicely segues into the next escaping issue. Somewhat comically `\e[` is actually a representation of `ESC`, it is therefore in itself an escape sequence marker that, yes, is in turn escaped by `\`. It's a riff on the old `\\\\\\\\\\` sort of joke. Now, significantly, we must be clear on the difference between the escape expressions for the terminal and the string substitutions of the prompt, in pseudo code:

   > `PROMPT="%{terminal colour stuff%}test %D%{terminal colour stuff%}"`

   Now what I suspect is happening, though I can't find any documentation to prove it, is that once ZSH has done its substitutions, or indeed during the substitution process, all literal characters, regardless of escape significations, are promoted to real characters¹. To yet further the farce, this promotion is likely done by escaping all the escape characters. For example if you actually want to print '\e' on the command line, you have to do `echo "\\\e"`. So to overcome *this* issue, we just need to make sure the 'terminal colour stuff' escape sequences get evaluated *before* being assigned to `PROMPT` and that can be done simply with the `$''` pattern, like so:

   > `PROMPT=$'%{\e[00m\e[38;5;245m%}test %D%{\e[00m%}'`

   Note that `$''` is of the same ilk as `$()` and `${}`, except that its only function is to interpret escape sequences.

[1] My suspicion for this is based on the fact that you can actually do something like the following:

> `PROMPT='$(date)'`

where `$(date)` serves the same purpose as `%D`, by printing a *live* version of the date for every new prompt output to the screen. What this specific examples serves to demonstrate is that the `PROMPT` variable should really be thought of as storage for a mini script, not a string (though admittedly there is overlap between the 2 concepts and thus stems confusion). Therefore, as a script, the string is *first* evaluated and *then* printed. I haven't looked at ZSH's prompt rendering code, but I assume such evaluation would benefit from native use of escape sequences. For example what if you wanted to pass an escape sequence as an argument to a command (a command that gets run for every prompt render) in the prompt? For example the following is functionally identical to the prompt discussed above:

> `PROMPT='%{$(print "\e[00m\e[38;5;245m")%}test $(date)%{$(print "\e[00m")%}'`

The escape sequences are stored literally and only interpreted at the moment of each prompt rendering.

Comment: The correct octal representation for \e is \033, not \003.